# Only 1st letter of streetnames capital?

Tags: leaflet

In the embedded map the street names are with capital letters. How can the street names on openstreetmap be with capital only the 1st letter and lower-case all the rest?

Thank you!

Comment: Check http://leafletjs.com/ first example. Street names of London are not all caps.

Answer (score 1):

As Jieter & FranceImage mention, you can do your styling with [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/studio).

We use the Text Transform control, as some of our points of interest require ALL CAPS, and some require None.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show openstreetmap maps with leaflet ... you can't.

You have to keep in mind that what you see are images downloaded from a server.

To achieve what you want you have to find a way to customize the data on a server before building the tiles (the images). 
For example https://www.mapbox.com/

Comment: Thank you for reply. But here http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Deploying_your_own_Slippy_Map leaflet is listed, also I did this but street names were with all letters capitals.

Comment: I think what FranceImage means is that Leaflet is only the application rendering of a Tile Source images, among them OpenStreetMap. The street names are part of the images, so there is nothing Leaflet can do to change them. You would need to get OSM **raw data** and generate your own images, with your own text styling rules (you should be able to do that with Mapbox service, hence FranceImage's link).

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to change existing tile layers, without using someting like [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/), but you can look through a big list of existing layers, for example those in [leaflet-providers](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/)